# Join count table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, count

i have a table like this:

```
 ID CAT1  CAT2  CAT3      DATE
 1  IT   NETW  cisco1  2015-11-26
 2  IT   NETW  cisco2  2015-11-26
 1  IT   NETW  cisco1  2015-11-27
 2  IT   NETW  cisco2  2015-11-27
 3  OT   VID   dist1   2015-11-26
 4  OT   VID   dist2   2015-11-26
 3  OT   VID   dist1   2015-11-27
 4  OT   VID   dist2   2015-11-27
 5  ET   ALT   flip1   2015-11-26
 6  ET   ALT   flip2   2015-11-26
 5  ET   ALT   flip1   2015-11-27
 6  ET   ALT   flip2   2015-11-27
ecc..
```

i need count output like this:

```
CAT1 CAT2   CAT3   COUNT(2015-11-26)  COUNT(2015-11-27)
 IT  NETW  cisco1        1                  1
 IT  NETW  cisco2        1                  1
 OT  VID   dist1         1                  1
 OT  VID   dist1         1                  1
 ET  ALT   flip1         1                  1
 ET  ALT   flip1         1                  1
```

as you can see they are copied with different date.
but same times there are same row with date 2015-11-27 that aren't with the 2015-11-26 and in that case the count should output  0 or null. Can you help me to do a single query? I'm using SQL Server 2008.

Comment: GROUP BY. Use CASE for conditional counting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `GROUP BY`. Use `CASE` expressions to do conditional counting:

```
select CAT1, CAT2, CAT3,
       count(case when DATE = '2015-11-26' then 1 end) as cnt_2015-11-26,
       count(case when DATE = '2015-11-27' then 1 end) as cnt_2015-11-27
from tablename
group by CAT1, CAT2, CAT3
```

**Edit**:

Also calculate the difference between cnt_2015-11-26 and cnt_2015-11-27 using a derived table:

```
select CAT1, CAT2, CAT3, cnt_2015-11-26, cnt_2015-11-27,
       cnt_2015-11-26 - cnt_2015-11-27 as difference
from
(
select CAT1, CAT2, CAT3,
       count(case when DATE = '2015-11-26' then 1 end) as cnt_2015-11-26,
       count(case when DATE = '2015-11-27' then 1 end) as cnt_2015-11-27
from tablename
group by CAT1, CAT2, CAT3
) dt
```

Comment: Perfect that is exactly what i wanted, what if i want to add another row that will be the difference bitween cnt_2015-11-26 - 2015-11-27?

Comment: I'd wrap the current query up into a derived table, and then fix the difference in the main query. I'll add that in a few minutes. Check back.

Comment: Perhaps adding `WHERE DATE IN ('2015-11-26','2015-11-27')` would improve performance. Try and see if there is any difference in speed.

Answer (score 2):

by using Cross Apply and Pivot also we can do

```
select id,
CAT1,
CAT2,
CAT3,
[2015-11-26] AS 'COUNT[2015-11-26]',
[2015-11-27] AS 'COUNT[2015-11-27]' from (
select id,CAT1,CAT2,CAT3,col,val from @t
    CROSS APPLY (values('2015-11-26',date),('2015-11-27',date))cs(col,val))T
    PIVOT(count(val) FOR COL IN ([2015-11-26],[2015-11-27]))P
```